# Dynamic html called into main html - Prevent over righting document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to call footer.html into main.html. Looks like document.write is overwriting the footer.html. How can I display `Date().getFullYear()` inside my main.html?

main.html (main page):

```
<script>
  $("#footer").load("footer.html");
</script>
```

footer.html (external file):

```
<div><span style="color:#444;">&copy; Comp <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script></span></div>
```

Comment: What's the problem you are having???

Comment: In my MAIN.HTML this does not show the words `&copy; Comp`. It only shows `2014`

Comment: document.write overwrites the `&copy; Comp`, don't use it.

Comment: `<div><span style="color:#444;"> ..... ` that works. But when I try to call it from my mail html page it only shows `2014`.

Comment: Is your code inside ready?

Comment: @C-link Nepal: Sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: @Kheema Pandey : How do I call an external page which includes the copyright date in to my main.html page?

Comment: @KheemaPandey: yes, the external page does not load. yes, both pages are in the same location

Comment: try to use $.get() method....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.write` overwrites your existing HTML. Try using `appendChild` with `createTextNode` like so (add an id to your span tag):

```
document.getElementById('copyright')
    .appendChild( document.createTextNode(new Date().getFullYear()) );
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejw1z5fd/)

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4av5d5tu/

You will notice that no jquery is necessary. All you need is the html:

```
<div><span style="color:#444;">&copy; Comp <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script></span></div>
```

the jQuery .load() function loads data from a server, which you do not require, thus you can remove it. The HTML alone with the inline script should be enough to get what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks but I need to load an external html page which includes the copyright date.